# How to select rows with max(:created_at (Rails 3, PostgreSQL)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

Want to get (this){example ⬇} data from db.

Have data like this :

```
=> #<Item id: 2330, asin: “7701C6RHIY", domain: "com”, title: “badfsd”, created_at: "2014-04-04 01:42:28">

(this) => #<Item id: 2330, asin: “7701C6RHIY", domain: "com”, title: “badfsd”, created_at: "2014-04-04 03:52:28">

=> #<Item id: 2330, asin: “7701C6RHIY", domain: "com”, title: “badfsd”, created_at: "2014-04-04 03:42:18">

=> #<Item id: 2330, asin: “7701C6RHIY", domain: "com”, title: “badfsd”, created_at: "2014-04-04 03:42:22”>
```

+

```
(this) => #<Item id: 4331, asin: “R901C6RHIY", domain: “ca”, title: “FSDs”, created_at: "2014-07-04 03:42:28">

=> #<Item id: 4331, asin: “R901C6RHIY", domain: “ca”, title: “FSDs”, created_at: "2014-04-04 03:42:28">

=> #<Item id: 4331, asin: “R901C6RHIY", domain: “ca”, title: “FSDs”, created_at: "2014-05-04 03:42:28">
```

+

```
(this) => #<Item id: 571, asin: "BSD1C6RHIY", domain: "co.jp", title: "BRIDGサイズ SCN20.A シルバー”, created_at: "2014-04-04 03:42:28">

=> #<Item id: 570, asin: "BSD1C6RHIY", domain: "co.jp", title: "BRIDGサイズ SCN20.A シルバー”, created_at: "2014-04-02 03:42:28">

=> #<Item id: 560, asin: "BSD1C6RHIY", domain: "co.jp", title: "BRIDGサイズ SCN20.A シルバー”, created_at: "2014-04-01 03:42:28">
```

Result something like (this) data with ids => 2330, 4331, 571

+++ UPDATE +++

Right now this is working for me:

```
 @item_registrations = ItemRegistration.find_all_by_user_id(current_user.id)
 @items = []
 @item_registrations.try(:each) do |i|
   @items += Item.where(:asin => i.asin, :domain => i.domain, :user_id => i    .user_id).order('created_at desc').limit(1)
 end
```

But, this stuff is slow, so, maybe, there is some other way.

+++ UPDATE2 +++

I want to do something like this:

```
@items = Item.where(:user_id => current_user.id).where(:created_at => ("SELECT m    ax(created_at) from Items"))
```

getting a msg ->

```
PG::InvalidDatetimeFormat: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "SELECT max(created_at) from Items"
LINE 1: ... "items"."user_id" = 1 AND "items"."created_at" = 'SELECT ma...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."user_id" = 1 AND "items"."created_at" = 'SELECT max(created_at) from Items' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: You want `Active Record` query or `Postgresql`?

Comment: Active Record preferable.

Comment: You want to retrive the records only with those ids right i.e, 2330,4331,571?

Comment: Nope, it just an example. I have tons of data. I want to get every distinct (asin & domain) rows where max(created_at)

Comment: You mean the latest created records?

Comment: yes, the latest created records will be ok.

Comment: Hi mate. Thank you for your help. I found other solution, I just posted it. But, really, thank you for your help, appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sql = "SELECT i.* from items i where i.created_at in (select max(i2.created_at) from items i2 group by i2.asin, i2.domain )
@items = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to retrieve the latest created records which are uniq,you can just do this

```
Item.select(:id).map(&:id).order("created_at DESC").uniq

                      OR

Item.uniq.pluck(:id).order("created_at DESC")

which gives you the latest created records which are unique

     #<Item id: 571, asin: "BSD1C6RHIY", domain: "co.jp", title: "BRIDGサイズ SCN20.A シルバー”, created_at: "2014-04-04 03:42:28">

     #<Item id: 2330, asin: “7701C6RHIY", domain: "com”, title: “badfsd”, created_at: "2014-04-04 03:52:28">

     #<Item id: 4331, asin: “R901C6RHIY", domain: “ca”, title: “FSDs”, created_at: "2014-07-04 03:42:28">
```

**Note:**

I'm not sure whether this is 100% correct.Please have try with it.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Getting this msg -> "Cannot visit Arel::Nodes::Distinct"

Comment: @whitesiroi According to this discussion https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7399 just restart your server and try again.

Comment: Yup, restart - did the trick
@items = Item.where(:user_id => current_user.id).uniq.order("created_at DESC")
I'm getting all data, I need only data that has max(:created_at) for asin & domain

Comment: Please have a try with this.`@items = item.select(:id).where(:user_id => current_user.id).uniq.order("created_at DESC")`

Comment: msg ▶︎：）
PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...ROM "items"  WHERE "items"."user_id" = 1 ORDER BY created_at...
                                                             ^
: SELECT  DISTINCT id FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."user_id" = 1 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: @items = Item.select(:id).where(:user_id => current_user.id).order("created_at DESC").uniq

PG::InvalidColumnReference: ERROR:  for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list
LINE 1: ...ROM "items"  WHERE "items"."user_id" = 1 ORDER BY created_at...  :)

Comment: & tried with  @items = Item.select(:id, :created_at).where(:user_id => current_user.id).order("created_at DESC").uniq

getting this msg -> wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I just updated my question, can you check it please :)

Comment: @whitesiroi those wrong number of arguments are due to using both `id` and `created_at` in select.Try either of the one.

Comment: I'm getting ORDERed result, but I just need rows with max(created_at) :)
Right now I'm getting like: B00IVXLF8Y 2014-03-27 03:25:20 UTC ; B00IVXLF8Y 2014-03-26 03:25:20 UTC ; B00IVXLF8Y 2014-03-22 03:25:20 UTC; .....